# Drupal 7: add new option to theme configuration

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

So I have created a subtheme witch his parent is Drupal Bootstrap theme. I would like to add an option to share a second logo in the page (I have googled but I have found nothing).

[image]

As you see in the image, I would like to add the option just where the red line is between "logotip" and "Nom del lloc" and create a variable to acces to the second logo like $second_logo.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- go to your theme
- create new file **theme-setting.php**
- implement the below hook "**hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter**"

  ```
  function <theme_name>_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {

      //add your variable field        
      $form['theme_settings']['second_logo'] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => t('Use the second logo'),
          '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('second_logo'),
      );
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'll edit my answer again, to let you know a complete example to upload a second logo, because it is the proper way to do it 
Create this file in your custom theme:

**theme-settings.php**

Use customthemename_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) hook

For example:

```
 function customthemename_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
        $form['second_logo'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Use the second logo'),
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('second_logo'),

    );
```

Add the variable to youcustomtheme.info file, like this:

```
settings[second_logo] = ''
```

Finally, just you can do this in your /sites/all/themes/customthemename/templates/html.tpl.php:

```
 <?php
      if (theme_get_setting('second_logo')): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo path_to_theme();  ?>/images/your_logo" />
   <?php endif;
```

That's it.

Please refer to the documentation: 
[Theme settings D7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/advanced/creating-advanced-theme-settings)

Comment: last line would be `$settings['customthemename_settings'] = 'logo_ub.png';`, no?

Comment: Please, refer to the previous code, because you need to upload your second logo, it is not a good practice define the logo in your customthemename.info file.

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Please have a look at Drupal Coding Standards https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards and please remove the distracting run code snippet feature from your code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got confused with the stackoverflow editor :)

Comment: I don't want that the user upload a image. The only I want is that the user can show or hide the logo. The logo will be in the sub-theme folder

Comment: OK, I edited my answer, if you just want to show or hide the second logo.